# Having an issue converting FLA to HTML5 with Scenes

Tags: flash, html5-canvas

Well,

I have an interactive FLA file running AS3 that has several scenes.  I tried converting the file to HTML5 canvas and it has separated all of my scenes into different files.    Does anyone know a way around this?
Please let me know.

**Thank you!**

Comment: Are you using Animate CC?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I just started using Animate CC.  It does exactly the same thing.